# How to plot data from different files?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot data from different text files. 
I've had to manipulate data so I could construct the graphic that I desire for just one document. All other documents are in the same way. But I can't see how I can plot all in one panel. The code that I tried for the loop of all files was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filenames=["b_10.txt","b_100.txt","b_500.txt","b_1000.txt"]
for i in filenames:
    with open(i) as f:
        data = f.read()
        data = data.split('\n')
        x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
        y = [row.split(' ')[-1] for row in data]
        x
        a=list(map(str.strip, y))
        trip_list = [item.strip('\tall\t') for item in y]
        yy = np.array(trip_list[1:12])
        yy
        xx= np.array(x[21:32])
        xx
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.hold(True)
    plt.ylabel('Precisão Interpolada')
    plt.xlabel('Recall')
    plt.plot(xx,yy,'-',label="Precisão Interpolada vs Recall")
    plt.show()
```

It gave me an error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
and a blank panel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuVtU.png)

Comment: Using a `for` loop?

Comment: It could be DavidG 20 as long as  it can work

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and why it isn't working

Comment: What the comment by @DavidG wants to tell you is that you should try using a for loop. Then, if it fails, edit the question asking for the problem you encounter.

Comment: @BrunoMiguelGonçalves Can you show an example of what your text files look like?

Comment: I've edited again and put a link with the notebook image,